# Can I post on Twitter a stock photo without paying?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, internet

Found a cool image: https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/photo/urban-crowds-of-people-from-above-royalty-free-image/1180113568

There are many jurisdictions:

- Twitter jurisdiction
- Getty Images jurisdiction
- my jurisdiction
- author jurisdiction

But I don't want to spend loads of dollar everytime I tweet an image.

## What does the IP & copyright & internet law say in 2021?

Comment: Is there a reason you think Twitter posts might somehow be exempt from copyright?

Comment: "Royalty Free" doesn't mean you don't have to pay for it before you use it, it just means that after you buy a license, you don't have to pay each time you use it.

Comment: @Studoku I think it is me asking a question. One could argue that copyright is applicable for commercial products. Twitter is entertainment. Non commercial. If I was making money from it - yes, I need to pay. Posting on Twitter? Illustrational purpose only. Free of charge. Unsure. Therefore question.

Comment: That's absolutely not how copyright works, copyrights are not just to protect commercial use...

Comment: If you don't want to spends loads of dollars every time you tweet an image, don't tweet copyrighted images.

Comment: @Figuringthingsout: You say, " If I was making money from it - yes, I need to pay", but copyright infringement law (in the USA) requires no proof of actual profits by the infringer or loss by the victim. In fact, you could be liable for "statutory damages" of up to $150,000 for each image infringed, absent plaintiff's proof of damages beyond that.

Comment: @Upnorth are there any known instances of enforcing such a court judgement? Twitter is operating under US jurisdiction. I actually like the watermark. It looks like "low effort" but it's actually good for the meme. Maybe I can pay the price and use the watermarked version for the LOLZ.

Comment: @Figuringthingsout  A 2019 appeals case of the 9th Circuit in California, Erikson v Kant, deals with 2011 website use of unlicensed photos as allegedly willful infringement, qualifying for the heightened statutory damages of $150,000 for each image. It also involves contributory and vicarious liability of a client for infringing acts of a third-party web developer.

Answer (score 4):

Reproducing someone else's copyrighted material without permission is a violation of that copyright. This includes using it to promote your Twitter account. This is a violation of copyright law and of Twitter's TOS.

There may be Fair Use exceptions- this question is arguably fair use. However, it's extremely unlikely your intended post counts.

In the case of the image in question, royalty-free means you pay for a single licence for that image and can then use it as much as you want (according to that licence). You can post that image in as many of your tweets as you like- you don't have to pay each time.

If you don't want to pay for images you use, use public domain images, images with licenses that allow you to use them, or create them yourself.

Comment: ...or ask GPT-3 to generate them for me :)